# How do you specify the size of a 3 Byte storage in XOR statement in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, intel

In my Linux Assembly program for IA-32 processors I got two storages.

```
inbuf: resb 3
outbuf: resb 4
```

`inbuf` really only needs 3 bytes and I don't like to waste any memory. Now, let's say I want to overwrite them with zeros like this:

```
xor [inbuf], inbuf
xor [outbuf], outbuf
```

nasm says that I need to specify the operation size, which is understandable. Now for `outbuf` this is no problem, because I can write

```
xor dword [outbuf], outbuf
```

instead, but apparently, there are no size keywords for arbitrary sizes as 3 byte. How can I specify the size of `inbuf`?

I am not really looking for a solution to overwrite a storage with zeros and I guess there are other ones that work just as well, but this would also solve my problem how to use something like

```
mov eax, inbuf
```

without getting a "size not specified" error.

Comment: Indeed there is no 3 byte operation size, you will have to synthesize it from 2+1 bytes for example. Even if there were, your code wouldn't do what you want, you are xoring with the address, not the value (which you can't do directly). Just stick to powers of two for efficiency. PS: `mov eax, inbuf` does not trigger the "size not specified" error because the size of `eax` is known and determines the operation size implicitly.

Comment: @Jester Using powers of 2 would be a little unsatisfying. What do you mean with adding 2 and 1 byte together? Can I do something like `xor byte+word [inbuf], inbuf` or is this syntacticly incorrect?

Comment: I mean, use 2 instructions. Also, as I said, you can't use `xor mem,mem` to zero (it doesn't take 2 memory operands). `mov word [inbuf], 0; mov byte [inbuf+2], 0` would work.

Comment: I recommend not aligning your data this way, because it causes tons of misaligned memory accesses, which slow your code down considerably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will add over Jester's correct answer in comments.

If you would insist on "xor-ing" the memory (doesn't make sense for zeroing, but may be worth for other values), then "xor 3B [inbuf],3B [inbuf]" can be done in x86 assembly like this:

```
mov  eax,[inbuf]   ; loads value from inbuf + 1B undef
xor  [inbuf],ax    ; word
shr  eax,16        ; al = b16..b23 of value @inbuf
xor  [inbuf+2],al  ; byte
```

The 4B dword variant:

```
mov  eax,[outbuf]
xor  [outbuf],eax
```

And all of that is horrible for zeroing, for zeroing this is better:

```
mov word [inbuf],0
mov byte [inbuf+2],0
mov dword [outbuf],0
```

Or eventually, if you have already zero in some 32b register:

```
xor eax,eax
mov [inbuf],ax
mov [inbuf+2],al
mov [outbuf],eax
```

You can access memory only for power-of-two sizes, and only for some of them, in 32b mode: 1, 2 and 4 with general purpose integer arithmetic.

And 8 or 10 with FPU. Oh yeah, 10 is not power of two, I know, it's special one only for some FP things.

And then there're various SIMD instructions, which can access even 128/256/512 bits (16,32 and 64 bytes).

Then non arithmetic special instructions can sometimes use additional extra sizes, like 5 or 6 maybe (I'm not even sure) with some far jumping, etc... Generally I wouldn't count them even as exception, as the whole x86 instruction decoding is using variable-byte-amount approach and the denominating size is 1B, so it's not about powers of two in that part.

Anyway, almost nobody works with 3 bytes only in Assembly, that's "incorrect" hexed size and bring lot of misfortune upon user, you should avoid it whenever possible.

Sometimes people stretch it so far, that even video ram consisting of RGB data is 32-bit-per-pixel aligned, wasting every 4th byte for "nothing" only like padding (25% of VRAM wasted and it was back in time, when RAM was **expensive**).

(Early the SVGA VESA modes did have also memory-efficient 24bit modes, but as the addressing per pixel is *3, it was very annoying to use in code, or even by HW accelerators ... nowadays it helps that most of the video ram usage is for textures, where 4th byte can store alpha or other additional information for pixel shader, so it's no more wasted memory, yet the size is 32 bit)

---

And how to load 3B value from memory:

For generic 3B load which must work all the time:

```
movzx eax,byte [inbuf+2]
shl   eax,16
mov   ax,[inbuf]
```

And when you know that 3B value is not at end of memory page followed by restricted memory page (so the value is either on address aligned by 4, or there's always another legal memory page after it):

```
mov  eax,[inbuf]      ; loads desired 3B + 1B garbage
and  eax,0x00FFFFFF   ; truncate it to 3B only
```

(this would crash on the read over memory page boundary when next memory page is restricted, like if "inbuf" is address 4093, and address 4096 is restricted to this process => illegal memory access crash, but that's usually not where you would have "inbuf" defined, so this shorter variant is usually shown as the correct solution, without this stupidly long explanation, when it actually *may* crash).

Comment: +1 for bringing up the hex-size problem. `mov word [inbuf],0
mov byte [inbuf+2],0` seems like a good solution though.

Comment: @JoeCocker: arbitrary continuous memory block can be also zeroed by `rep stos[b/w/d]`, for example to clear 312B at "outblock": `mov edi,outblock | xor eax,eax | mov ecx,312/4 | rep stosd` .. if the addresses are aligned, and the size is non-trivial, this may be fastest way. For fixed sizes like 3 or 64 either the several `mov byte/word/dword [aligned_address],0` is best for shorter sizes, for longer like 64B there may be some SIMD variant. For larger counts usually the `rep stosd` is on par with SIMD optimized solutions, as it will be internally recompiled into ~optimal uops subroutine.

Comment: BTW notice the recurring theme of address alignment, and sizes divisible by power-of-two (at least 4 or more). This has big performance implications, whenever reasonable, make your data land at 4/8/16 byte boundaries, and have such size as well, so for example 3B inbuf would be 4B inbuf almost all the time, and only where the 3B size really matters (like storing bytes into file, or sending it to some peripheral) the 3B would be used. Otherwise the 4th byte garbage would be used together when possible, to "pad" it up to 4B size.